# Angular ng-repeat - how to join or combine data from different arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to join/combine two arrays in angular ng-repeat.

Simple example book/author where I want to print book titles with coresponding author name.

Books are in one array, authors in another.

How to join data in this example?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1jxsh0x3/

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.authors = [{
    id: "1",
    name: "John"
  }, {
    id: "2",
    name: "Peter"
  }, {
    id: "3",
    name: "Mark"
  }];
  
  $scope.books = [{
    id: "1",
    id_author: "3",
    name: "Book Lorem"
  }, {
    id: "2",
    id_author: "1",
    name: "Book Ipsum"
  }, {
    id: "3",
    id_author: "1",
    name: "Book Dark"
  }];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="book in books">
    <div>Book title: {{book.name}}</div>
    <div>Authors name: {{authors[$index].name}}</div>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to show the data based on the `id` which is unique. Not index?

Comment: @SaiUnique, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** At least AngularJS 1.2 is required

I would use angulars filter:

```
<div>
    Authors name: {{authors[$index].name}}
</div>
```

to:

```
<div>
    Authors name: {{(authors | filter:{'id': book.id_author}:true)[0].name}}
</div>
```

What we are doing here is taking the array `authors` and `filter` it by the expression `'id': book.id_author` and we take the `.name` of the first element of this filtering (`[0]`).

Just in case you could check if you actually have the author in your array:

```
<div>
    Authors name: {{(authors | filter:{'id': book.id_author}:true) 
                     ? (authors | filter:{'id': book.id_author}:true)[0].name
                     : 'Unknown'}}
</div>
```

Best regards

PS (**EDIT**): fiddle with angular 1.2.6 -> http://jsfiddle.net/gqqv9k38/1/

Comment: There is a problem if there is for example author with id:11, it shows that author, not author with id:1

Comment: Hi, it is not `strict` but `true` what should be on the code, I already edited it. The reason it does not work on the fiffle is because the fiddle is using angular 1.0.1, is this the angular version you are using?

Comment: The fiddle with angular 1.2.6 for example http://jsfiddle.net/gqqv9k38/1/

Answer (score 2):

1. You can create custom `findAuthor` method
2. Use common `filter` with `strict` to select exactly needed author `id` instead of similar

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope){

  $scope.authors = [{
    id: "1",
    name: "John"
  }, {
    id: "11",
    name: "Peter"
  }, {
    id: "3",
    name: "Mark"
  }];
  
  $scope.books = [{
    id: "1",
    id_author: "3",
    name: "Book Lorem"
  }, {
    id: "2",
    id_author: "1",
    name: "Book Ipsum"
  }, {
    id: "3",
    id_author: "1",
    name: "Book Dark"
  }];
  
    
  $scope.findAuthor = function(id){
    return $scope.authors.find(function(x){
     return x.id == id
   })};
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<h4>1. findAuthor metod</h4>
<div ng-app='app', ng-controller='ctrl'>  
  <div ng-repeat="book in books">
      <div>Book title: {{book.name}}</div>
      <div>Authors name: {{findAuthor(book.id_author).name}}</div>
      <hr>
  </div>
  
<h4>2. With help of filter</h4>    
  <div ng-repeat="book in books">
    <div>Book title: {{book.name}}</div>
    <div>Authors name: {{(authors | filter: {'id': book.id_author}: strict)[0].name}}</div>
    <hr>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the most optimized solution for your problem.

Put the below code in your controller file -

```
$scope.entries = [];
angular.forEach($scope.books,function(entry) {
    var author_name;
    var searchField = "id";
    var searchVal = entry.id_author;
    author_name = getAuthorName(searchField,searchVal,$scope.authors)
    $scope.SubInformation['author_name'] = author_name;
    $scope.entries.push(angular.extend(entry,$scope.SubInformation);   
});

function getAuthorName(searchField,searchVal,authors){
    for (var i=0 ; i < authors.length ; i++)
    {
        if (authors[i][searchField] == searchVal) {
            return authors[i]['name'];
        }
    }
}
```

And update your view file with below code :

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="book in entries">
    <div>Book title: {{book.name}}</div>
    <div>Authors name: {{book.author_name}}</div>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="book in books">
    <div>Book title: {{book.name}}</div>
    <div>Authors name: {{getAuthorName(book.id_author)}}</div>
</div>
```

in js:

```
$scope.getAuthorName(id) {
    var name;
    name = $scope.authors.find(function(author) {
        if(author.id_author === id) {
            return author.name;
        }
    }) 
    return name;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

create the function and filter the name according to id

```
$scope.getName = function(obj){

    return $scope.authors.find(o=>{
      if(o.id == obj.id_author){return o }
    })
  }
```

call it like this

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="book in books">
    <div>Book title: {{book.name}}</div>
    <div>Authors name: {{getName(book).name}}</div>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fxkcjspy/)

Answer (score 0):

You can merge both JSON data into new array

```
 var  newArray= authors.map(x => Object.assign(x, books.find(y => y.id == x.id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply compare the values and add it to the `books` model. It can be done as shown below:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    function MyCtrl($scope) {

      $scope.authors = [{
        id: "1",
        name: "John"
      }, {
        id: "2",
        name: "Peter"
      }, {
        id: "3",
        name: "Mark"
      }];
      
      $scope.books = [{
        id: "1",
        id_author: "3",
        name: "Book Lorem"
      }, {
        id: "2",
        id_author: "1",
        name: "Book Ipsum"
      }, {
        id: "3",
        id_author: "1",
        name: "Book Dark"
      }];
      
      
      for(var i = 0; i < $scope.books.length; i++){
          var id = $scope.books[i].id_author;
          for(var j = 0; j < $scope.authors.length; j++){
              if($scope.authors[j].id ==  $scope.books[i].id_author ){
               $scope.books[i].authorName =  $scope.authors[j].name;
              }
          }
      }
      
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app = "myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="book in books">
            <div>Book title: {{book.name}}</div>
            <div>Authors name: {{book.authorName}}</div>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer, with demo :) ..your author array must be sorted in my case ;)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.authors = [{
    id: "1",
    name: "John"
  }, {
    id: "2",
    name: "Peter"
  }, {
    id: "3",
    name: "Mark"
  }];

  $scope.books = [{
    id: "1",
    id_author: "3",
    name: "Book Lorem"
  }, {
    id: "2",
    id_author: "1",
    name: "Book Ipsum"
  }, {
    id: "3",
    id_author: "1",
    name: "Book Dark"
  }];



}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="book in books">
    <div>Book title: {{book.name}}</div>
    <div>Authors name: {{authors[book.id_author -1].name}}</div>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```